# jQuery move div after text-input change

Tags: jquery, css, html, position

I'm trying to move an image holder div to specific x and y coordinates after input from two separate text field inputs have been changed. Below is the code for just the x coordinate.

Here is a jfiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/dhpkW/)**

```
var img1x;
var img1y;
var img1position;

img1position = $( "#img1" ).position();
img1x = img1position.left;
img1y = img1position.top;
```

I've tried this and it only moves the div if the imput value is "0". it won't move for anything else:

```
$("#img1x").change(function() {
  //alert("img1x: " +img1x);
    $( "#img1" ).css('left', $( "#img1x" ).val());
});
```

and I've tried this and it does nothing.

```
$("#img1x").change(function() {
  img1x = $( "#img1x" ).val();
  //alert("img1x: " +img1x);
    $( "#img1" ).css('left', img1x);
});
```

Comment: Andrew is right, you might try use http://api.jquery.com/animate/ for a fluid transition then you wouldn't need the `px` in the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `'px'`:

```
$("#img1x").change(function() {
  img1x = $( "#img1x" ).val();
  alert("img1x: " +img1x);
    $( "#img1" ).css('left', img1x + "px");
});
```

Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/VNqqx/

The reason `0` works is because `left: 0` is valid CSS.

Comment: Right, of course, I was forgetting "px"! Thanks! The cold medication is playing tricks on me.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding 'px', or * 1 to get an int:

```
$( "#img1" ).css('left', img1x + 'px');
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/dhpkW/1/

Answer (score 1):

Add a "px" to your left value:

```
$( "#img1" ).css('left', img1x+'px');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this for fluid transition

```
$("#img1x").change(function () {
    img1x = $("#img1x").val();
    alert("img1x: " + img1x);
    $("#img1").animate({
        'left': img1x
    }, 700);
});
```

You don't need the `px` then.

Check it out http://jsfiddle.net/dhpkW/6/